# How to add multiple inventory files in command line while executing a playbook

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory

I am having a playbook with two different plays

```
Sample.yml
    - name : Play1
      hosts: Host1
      tasks:
       ...
    - name: Play2
      hosts: Host2
      tasks:
       ...
```

I need to run this playbook with two different hosts(*Host1 and Host2*) and these two different hosts are present in two separate files(*Hostfile1 and Hostfile2*) under inventory/ directory.

```
inventory/
   Hostfile1
   Hostfile2
   .
   .
   HostfileN
```

I want to know how to include two different hosts file while running the playbook. I know by including the entire folder (*inventory/*) in command line we can achieve this but I have lot of hosts files inside inventory/ folder so this option will load unused hosts file.

I tried to run like below

```
ansible-playbook -i inventory/Hostfile1,Hostfile2 sample.yml
```

But this didn't work. So, do anyone know how to run the playbook by providing multiple hosts file in command line?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Just simply provide `-i` multiple times

`ansible-playbook -i inventory/Hostfile1 -i inventory/Hostfile2 sample.yml`

Comment: So, this is something you MIGHT not want to do. If any of the groupvars are different, it's going to use the last inventory's version for ALL instances

Answer (score 5):

I wanted to clarify the above answer. The reason the proposal doesn't work is that if ansible sees a ',' in the value of the -i flag, it treats this as an inventory list. Using your example:

ansible-playbook -i inventory/Hostfile1,Hostfile2 sample.yml

Ansible will attempt to run the playbook "sample.yml" on the machines "inventory/Hostfile1" and "Hostfile2".

That's why you must specify -i multiple times.