# Can "ansible_ssh_common_args" variable be used for different child groups in inventory file?

Tags: ansible

I am trying to connect to 2 hosts from 2 different ProxyJumpHost.

For example:
hostname1 is reachable only via ProxyJumpHost1
hostname2 is reachable only via ProxyJumpHost2

when I give "ansible_ssh_common_args" variable separately for the group but ansible is picking only one ProxyJumpHost information and trying to connect both the hosts from there.

My inventory yaml file looks like this

```
all_nodes:
  children:
    preprod:
      children:
        PRE_CH:
          vars:
            ansible_ssh_common_args: '-o ProxyCommand="sshpass -p {{ password }} ssh -W %h:%p -q {{ user }}@<ProxyJumpHost1>"'
          hosts:
            hostname1:
              ansible_host: <IP_Address>
            hostname2:
              ansible_host: <IP_Address>
        PRE_NL:
          vars:
            ansible_ssh_common_args: '-o ProxyCommand="sshpass -p {{ password }} ssh -W %h:%p -q {{ user }}@<ProxyJumpHost1>"'
          hosts:
            hostname3:
              ansible_host: <IP_Address>
            hostname4:
              ansible_host: <IP_Address>
```

My expectation is to connect the correct host via correct ProxyJumpHost.

But actually it takes only one ProxyJumpHost value and tries to connect all the hosts via that.

Answer (score 2):

In your example both vars are identical

```yaml
PRE_CH:
  vars:
    ansible_ssh_common_args: '-o ProxyCommand="sshpass -p {{ password }} ssh -W %h:%p -q {{ user }}@<ProxyJumpHost1>"'

PRE_NL:
  vars:
    ansible_ssh_common_args: '-o ProxyCommand="sshpass -p {{ password }} ssh -W %h:%p -q {{ user }}@<ProxyJumpHost1>"'
```

Q: ***"For example, hostname1 is reachable only via ProxyJumpHost1 hostname2 is reachable only via ProxyJumpHost2. I expect to connect the correct host via correct ProxyJumpHost."***

A: Set *ansible_ssh_common_args* for each host

```yaml
hosts:
  hostname1:
    ansible_host: <IP_Address>
    ansible_ssh_common_args: '... {{ user }}@<ProxyJumpHost1>"'
  hostname2:
    ansible_host: <IP_Address>
    ansible_ssh_common_args: '... {{ user }}@<ProxyJumpHost2>"'
```

Q: ***"What if I have 2 more hosts that I can connect via ProxyJumpHost1 and 2 more via ProxyJumpHost2? In total, I will have 3 hosts via ProxyJumpHost1 and 3 hosts via ProxyJumpHost2"***

A: For example (for simplicity and modularity) create inventory file *gates.ini* with two other groups *gate1* and *gate2*. Add this file to the inventory either in the config, or command line. Remove *ansible_ssh_common_args* from other inventory files

```ini
[gate1]
hostname1
hostname2
hostname3
[gate1:vars]
ansible_ssh_common_args='-o ProxyCommand="sshpass -p {{ password }} ssh -W %h:%p -q {{ user }}@<ProxyJumpHost1>"'

[gate2]
hostname4
hostname5
hostname6
[gate2:vars]
ansible_ssh_common_args='-o ProxyCommand="sshpass -p {{ password }} ssh -W %h:%p -q {{ user }}@<ProxyJumpHost2>"'
```

See

- [How do I configure a jump host to access servers that I have no direct access to?](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/faq.html#how-do-i-configure-a-jump-host-to-access-servers-that-i-have-no-direct-access-to).
- [How to add multiple inventory files in command line while executing a playbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54904433/how-to-add-multiple-inventory-files-in-command-line-while-executing-a-playbook)

Comment: But wouldn't that be redundant ? That's the reason why we are having group separation.

Comment: [Redundant](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/redundant)? hostname1 goes to ProxyJumpHost1 and hostname2 goes to ProxyJumpHost2. What is repeating?

Comment: what if I have 2 more hosts that I will be able to connect via ProxyJumpHost1 and 2 more via ProxyJumpHost2. In total I will have 3 hosts via ProxyJumpHost1 and 3 hosts via ProxyJumpHost2